# ImagickException with message Postscript delegate failed on MAMP 3.0.5

Tags: php, macos, pdf, imagemagick, imagick

Im trying to convert a PDF to a png file using MAMP 3.0.5.  I know that my PHP code works as it works fine on our Linux server...

I have setup MAMP 3.0.5 on my Mac OSX 10.8.5 and when I run the script to convert the PDF to png file I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'Postscript delegate failed `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/timesheets.com/saas/public_html/timesheets1/timesheets/Daisy_Morris_53635951154c7.pdf': No such file or directory @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/713'<

Please help, this is driving me crazy!

Comment: did you ever get any more information on this?  i am dealing with the same thing currently.

Comment: Hi Jacob, no I still haven't solved this issue.  I had parked the problem until now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help. I just ran into the same issue and solved it a few hours later.

My first instinct was to make sure PHP was looking at the right PATH. For me, it was this:

```
putenv('PATH=' . getenv('PATH') . ':/usr/local/bin');
```

That didn't seem to help on its own, but I left the code in there because at some point GhostScript is going to need to know where to find those libpng files.

My next step was to examine MAMP's Apache error log. I found this as the probable culprit:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libpng16.16.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/gs
Reason: Incompatible library version: gs requires version 29.0.0 or later, but libpng16.16.dylib provides version 23.0.0
```

Very strange, because my libpng in /usr/local/lib is up to date (1.6.12).

After much trial and error, I found that as of 3.0.5, MAMP is overriding with its own libpng files, in /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib

I removed libpng16.16.dylib from /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib, restarted MAMP, tried again, and got this error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/gs
Reason: Incompatible library version: gs requires version 18.0.0 or later, but libfreetype.6.dylib provides version 17.0.0
```

Well that's something different, so I removed libfreetype.6.dylib from /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib as well, and restarted MAMP.

At this point, everything began working. At least for me, the two steps were to make sure PHP's PATH is looking at the right directory, and then to remove the offending files from MAMP's included libpng library, forcing PHP to use the up-to-date libpng files in /usr/local/lib.

Comment: glad this worked for you.  I realized in my notes below i had already done this libpng fix as part of a different problem I was having with ffmpeg, so when i got stuck on ghost script it was only a one step solution. Didn't think about that until I saw this solution.  Nice work Dave.

Comment: putenv('PATH=' . getenv('PATH') . ':/usr/local/bin'); var_dump(getenv('PATH')); doesnt work - continue returns '/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin'

Answer (score 2):

I just found this blog post: http://lamp-ios.com/?p=216

The problem was that MAMP pro's PATH variable doesn't include the path the ghost script, which ImageMagick uses under the hood on PDF manipulation.

The steps to fix it were:

1. get the path to ghost script by typing "which gs" in the console
2. in your php:
   putenv('PATH=' . getenv('PATH') . ':/opt/local/bin/');

where /opt/local/bin/ is the path to your gs install

Comment: I just tried this but it's still reporting the same error...Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'Postscript delegate failed `

Comment: what did you set your env path to?  you didn't add the /gs to the path right?

Comment: also, i think you have to be using MAMP Pro for this to work.  Image Magick is only included in the pro version by default.  You'd have to configure it for the Basic version

Comment: Hi - this is what I set my env path to: putenv('PATH=' . getenv('PATH') . ':/usr/local/bin/gs');

Comment: Also, I am using MAMP Pro version 3.0.5.

Comment: Sorry, should have been more clear, it's the path up to where gs is located.  So you should put: putenv('PATH=' . getenv('PATH') . ':/usr/local/bin/');  Leaving out the gs.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying again.  It's still not working after I change my script to contain that line of code :(  It's important to note that MAMP Pro 3.0.5 comes pre compiled with gs so not sure if this fix will apply to me?

Comment: I Just had to configure mamp pro on another machine, but after the install it didn't seem to have gs running after it installed the MAMP components.  So i had to install gs and then do this same fix to get it working

Comment: Which version of MAMP did you install? What commands did you use to install gs? Sorry for all the questions but any input is greatly appreciated. This has been driving me mad now for months...

Comment: i used 3.0.5 for mamp.  I just thought of something else, what do you see when you type 'which php' in the console?

Comment: So that might be part of the problem. I think you have to point php to the MAMP install.  so you can add: 
alias php='/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/bin/php'
in your ~/.bash_profile

Comment: Ok, I added this line to my bash profile, but i'm still getting the same error arrghhh!!!!

Comment: Error: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'Postscript delegate failed `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/domain.com/saas/public_html/simplytimesheets1/timesheets/Bradley_Exall_53be520bb2ae0.pdf': No such file or directory @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/713' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/domain.com/saas/public_html/simplytimesheets1/classes/contractor.class.php:1757

Comment: I just did "which php" but still get "/usr/bin/php"

Comment: putenv('PATH=' . getenv('PATH') . ':/usr/local/bin'); var_dump(getenv('PATH')); doesnt work - continue returns '/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin'