# PHP SVG read on OSX Mavericks (MAMP 3) using Imagick

Tags: php, macos, svg, mamp, imagick

I have nearly the same problem like here:
[ImagickException with message Postscript delegate failed on MAMP 3.0.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23424144/imagickexception-with-message-postscript-delegate-failed-on-mamp-3-0-5)

I would like to read an SVG file (5 set Venn Diagram), which I created with php and I would like to write it out to a png/jpeg or whatever file... nothing work. It breaks on the 3rd line:

```
$im = new Imagick();
$svg = $venn_diagram;
$im->readImageBlob($svg);
$im->setImageFormat("jpeg");
$im->adaptiveResizeImage(720, 445); 
$im->writeImage($folder . 'output_venn_diagram.png');
$im->clear();
$im->destroy();
```

With this:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/blob.c/BlobToImage/359' in /myphp.php:500 Stack trace: #0 /myphp.php(500): Imagick->readimageblob('<svg version='1...') #1 {main} thrown in /myphp.php on line 500
```

It breaks also with this very simplified SVG also:

```
<svg version='1.0' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' width='746' height='742' viewBox='-362 -388 746 742' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='no'>
    <defs>
        <ellipse id='ellipse' cx='36' cy='-56' rx='160' ry='320' />
        <g id='ellipses'>
            <use xlink:href='#ellipse' fill='#0000ff' />
            <use xlink:href='#ellipse' fill='#0099ff' transform='rotate(72)' />
        </g>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

I don't really know what to do:

- MAMP / php running.
- I have SVG specification in the beginning of my file, I checked.
- I installed, uninstalled, reinstalled (with brew) imagick several times.
- I restarted MAMP also.

Do somebody know what to do?

Thanks for help!

- OS X Mavericks 10.9.3
- MAMP 3.05
- php 5.5.10
- imagemagick 6.8.9-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your SVG isn't valid xml and so isn't valid SVG

Add this to the start of the SVG:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

And it should work. The complete code that works for me is:

```
  $svg = <<< END
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg version='1.0' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' width='746' height='742' viewBox='-362 -388 746 742' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='no'>
    <defs>
        <ellipse id='ellipse' cx='36' cy='-56' rx='160' ry='320' />
        <g id='ellipses'>
            <use xlink:href='#ellipse' fill='#0000ff' />
            <use xlink:href='#ellipse' fill='#0099ff' transform='rotate(72)' />
        </g>
    </defs>
</svg>

END;


        $image = new \Imagick();

        $image->readImageBlob($svg);
        $image->setImageFormat("jpg");
        header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
        echo $image;
```

Produces this image:

[image]

Comment: Tried it with <?xml version='1.0'?> and <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?> also. Sadly none of these worked...

Comment: Thanks it worked! Fine. Something happpend in the last time. Your code works!