# How to read SVG string in Imagick?

Tags: php, svg, imagick

I have a string containing markup for an svg element.

```
<svg id="someId" width="300" height="300">
    <polygon id="another_id" fill="green" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" points="200,100 131,5 19,41 19,159 131,195 "></polygon>
</svg>
```

How can I read this string in Imagick and display it.

```
$svg = '<svg id="someId" width="300" height="300"><polygon id="another_id" fill="green" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" points="200,100 131,5 19,41 19,159 131,195 "></polygon>
</svg>';

$image = new Imagick();
// This is not working. 
$image->readImageBlob($svg);
$image->setImageFormat("png");
header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo $image;
```

How can I read this svg string so that I can proceed with doing other stuffs. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP SVG read on OSX Mavericks (MAMP 3) using Imagick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24387379/php-svg-read-on-osx-mavericks-mamp-3-using-imagick)

Answer (score 8):

You have to add `<?xml version="1.0"?>` in the begining of $svg variable.

This code works for me:

```
$svg = '<?xml version="1.0"?><svg id="someId" width="300" height="300"><polygon id="another_id" fill="green" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" points="200,100 131,5 19,41 19,159 131,195 "></polygon></svg>';
$image = new Imagick();
$image->readImageBlob($svg);
$image->setImageFormat("png");
header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo $image;
```